# I want to insert data in mongodb using node js....but it is showing......"ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

```
// model
const userModel= mongoose.model('userModel',userSchema)

    (async function createUser(){
    let user={
        name:'Hyder',
        email:'hyder123@gmail.com',
        password:'12345678',
        confirmPassword:'12345678'
    };
    let data= await userModel.create(user)
    console.log(data)
})();
```

Comment: Have you tired ``const UserModel= mongoose.model('UserModel',userSchema)``, also check: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.